# How can I make one (method|function|IDK) in Ruby do the same thing as another?

Tags: ruby, function, twitter, methods, alias

Check out https://github.com/ip2k/earthquake/blob/master/lib/earthquake/commands.rb#L106.

I want to basically do `alias :rt :retweet` but that doesn't work

```
command %r|^:retweet\s+(\d+)$|, :as => :retweet do |m|
  target = twitter.status(m[1])
  if confirm("retweet 'RT @#{target["user"]["screen_name"]}: #{target["text"]}'")
    async_e { twitter.retweet(m[1]) }
  end
end

command %r|^:retweet\s+(\d+)\s+(.*)$|, :as => :retweet do |m|
  target = twitter.status(m[1])
  text = "#{m[2]} #{config[:quotetweet] ? "QT" : "RT"} @#{target["user"]  ["screen_name"]}: #{target["text"]} (#{target["id"]})"
  if confirm("unofficial retweet '#{text}'")
    async_e { twitter.update(text) }
  end
end
```

How can I make `:rt` do the same as `:retweet` without just re-defining that entire block but with `:rt` in place of `:retweet` (which I've done to get it working, but it's not a good solution and I know that there has to be a better way).

Answer (score 0):

The `command` method is defined here:

https://github.com/ip2k/earthquake/blob/master/lib/earthquake/input.rb#L44

If you look at the body, it looks like you should just omit the block to create an alias:

```rb
command %r|^:retweet\s+(\d+)$|, :as => :rt
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate? `command %r|^:retweet\s+(\d+)$|, :as => :rt` doesn't fix anything.  Can't I do something like `command %r|^:retweet\s+(\d+)\s+(.*)$|, :as => :retweet or :rt do |m|` or maybe `command %r|^:retweet\s+(\d+)\s+(.*)$|, :as => :retweet | :rt do |m|`  Sorry, I don't know Ruby at all and I'm just trying to make Earthquake more usable.